# PHP and backslashes in strings

Tags: php, string, escaping, backslash

Can anyone tell me what is happening here?

```
<?php
// true
var_dump('\\ ' === '\ ');

// false
var_dump('\\\\ ' === '\\ ');

// true
var_dump('\\\\ ' === '\\\ ');
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the strings?

Comment: Yeah, dumped the hexcodes. They're really different, it seems that a \\ gets collapsed to \ for some reason, but it's in a single-quoted string, it shouldn't happen there.

Comment: There's no difference whether a string is single or double quoted. The escape character works identically in both cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\` inside a string literal introduces several types of escape sequences, `\\` is the escape sequence for a literal "\". But, `\`s that don't resolve to an escape sequence are also taken as literal "\".

Therefor, `'\\ '` stands for the string "\ ", `'\\\\ '` stands for the string "\\ ", just as `'\\\ '`. Try:

```
echo '\\\\ ';   -> \\
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single.

Comment: I had no idea that \\ works in a single-quoted string, thought it only works on ' itself.

Comment: @DaliborKarlović It is set up like that so you can have a single quoted string that ends with a backslash, if you couldn't escape the backslash you wouldn't be able to wrap `string\ ` in single quotes.

Comment: Yeah, I get it, my bad is that I was trying to use it inside a regex searching for a literal \n (not a control char), so preg_quote('#\n#') produced a string which matched, but var_dump()-ing the value produced by preg_quote() and using that instead did not.

Now I had to use #(\\\n){2,}#

Answer (score 4):

In single quoted strings, no escape sequences are interpolated. A backslash is only an escape character if it immediately precedes a single quote, **or a backslash**.

So:

```
var_dump('\\ '); // String (2) "\ "
var_dump('\ '); // String (2) "\ "
// They do match

var_dump('\\\\ '); // String (3) "\\ "
var_dump('\\ '); // String (2) "\ "
// They don't match

var_dump('\\\\ '); // String (3) "\\ "
var_dump('\\\ '); // String (3) "\\ "
// They do match
```

This is expected and documented behaviour, although it can be difficult to wrap you head around on the face of it.

Answer (score 1):

In 1st example you're comparing

```
"\ " and "\ " which is TRUE
```

in 2nd

```
"\\ " and "\ " which is FALSE
```

in 3rd

```
"\\ " and "\\ " which is TRUE
```

If you print out your strings

```
$s = array('\ ', '\\ ', '\\\ ', '\\\\ ');
var_dump($s);
```

you'll get

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "\ "
  [1]=>
  string(2) "\ "
  [2]=>
  string(3) "\\ "
  [3]=>
  string(3) "\\ "
}
```

All double-slashes `'\\'` have been converted into single-slashes `'\'` and sigle-slashes remain the same. Escaping works the same way inside single and double-quoted strings.