# PHP echo with single quotes and double quotes

Tags: php, double, echo, quotes

I have to echo a blob image in a carousel but I am not able to use single quotes for the img tag line because of the base64_encode() can someone explain me how to use the double quotes for the img line. Thanks !!!!

Here is my code :

```
    echo "
        <div id=\"Carousel$i\"  class=\"myCarousel carousel slideCarousel\" data-ride=\"carousel\" data-interval=\"5000\">
            <ol class=\"carousel-indicators\">
                <li data-target=\"#Carousel$i\" data-slide-to=\"0\" class=\"active\"></li>

            <li data-target=\"#Carousel$i\" data-slide-to=\"1\"></li>
            <li data-target=\"#Carousel$i\" data-slide-to=\"2\"></li>
            <li data-target=\"#Carousel$i\" data-slide-to=\"3\"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class=\"carousel-inner\" role=\"listbox\">
            <div class=\"item active\">";
                // HEREEEEE !!!!!!
                echo '<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'\"/>';
            echo "</div>

            <div class=\"item\">
                <img class=\"slideimage\" src=\"images/diving3.jpg\" alt=\"Chania\">
            </div>

            <div class=\"item\">
                <img class=\"slideimage\" src=\"images/Ambergris-Divers-PADI-Scuba-Course.jpg\" alt=\"Chania\">
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class=\"left carousel-control\" href=\"#Carousel$i\" role=\"button\" data-slide=\"prev\">
            <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>
            <span class=\"sr-only\">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class=\"right carousel-control\" href=\"#Carousel$i\" role=\"button\" data-slide=\"next\">
            <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>
            <span class=\"sr-only\">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
";
```

Comment: What does "I am not able to use single quotes for the img tag line because of the base64_encode()" mean? What problem are you having, exactly? Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In single quotes the backslash only escapes itself and the single quote. Otherwise it will remain as literal.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908002/php-and-backslashes-in-strings

Comment: I am very very sorry I mean I do not know how to echo this :  <img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'\"/>

Comment: using double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (stop using double quotes for echo-statements, just to avoid concatenating some strings.

```
echo '
    <div id="Carousel'.$i.'"  class="myCarousel carousel slideCarousel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#Carousel'.$i.'" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#Carousel'.$i.'" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#Carousel'.$i.'" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#Carousel'.$i.'" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="data:image/jpeg; base64,'.base64_encode($image).'">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="slideimage" src="images/diving3.jpg" alt="Chania">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img class="slideimage" src="images/Ambergris-Divers-PADI-Scuba-Course.jpg" alt="Chania">
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel'.$i.'" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel'.$i.'" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working and sorry again I made a mistake while writing my question, by the way do you know what is the best way to display a BLOB image ? Using base64_encode or using a query like this <img src="image.php?id=<?php echo $image_id; ?>" />